# Rioxarray.merge.merge_datasets unable to merge xarray datasets

Tags: python, rasterio, rioxarray, xarray

I am working with geospatial data and have been previously using rasterio's merge function to join adjacent tiles together. For memory reasons I have switched from using in-memory rasters to xarray datasets and using rioxarray's merge function instead (which is rasterio.merge.merge but in a wrapper). The piece of code in question is (It is a long script and the data itself is very large on a server so I apologise for not being able to provide that, but I have included the relevant packages for this snippet of code):

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import xarray as xr
import rioxarray as rio
from rioxarray.merge import merge_datasets
import rasterio as rs

def custom_method(old_data,new_data,old_nodata,new_nodata,index=None,roff=None,coff=None):
    old_data[:]=np.nansum([old_data,new_data],axis=0)

# pixel coordinates for each 1024x1024 tile
xlocs = np.array([[i for i in range(0,1024,1)],]*1024)
ylocs = np.transpose(xlocs)


datasets = []

# 'grid' is a UK tile grid

grids = ['TL63','TL64']

for grid in grids:
# gets appropriate file and then we have....
    with h5py.File(file,'r') as f:
        bounds = f[grid].attrs['Bounds']
        bands = list(f[grid])
        crs = f[grid].attrs['CRS']
        data = np.array([np.array(f[grid+f'/{b}']).astype(np.float64) for b in bands])
        gt = rs.transform.from_bounds(bounds[0],bounds[1],bounds[2],bounds[3],X,Y)
    f.close()
    
    # convert pixel coords to EPSG:27700
    lon,lat = (xlocs,ylocs)*gt
    data_dict = {}

    for i,band in enumerate(bands):
        data_dict[band]=(['x','y'],data[i])
    
    ds = xr.Dataset(data_vars=data_dict,
                        coords={
                            'longitude':(['x','y'], lon),
                            'latitude':(['x','y'], lat)
                        },
    )
    ds.rio.write_crs(crs,inplace=True)
    ds.rio.write_transform(gt,inplace=True)
    ds=ds.transpose('y','x') # merge errors said this was necessary
    datasets.append(ds)

merged_ds = merge_datasets(datasets,nodata=np.nan,method=custom_method,bounds=bounds)
```

When run, the error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/My Passport for Mac/python_script/memory.py", line 30, in <module>
    arr,transf=fn.merger(grids,'2020-12-30','prediction',clip=True,boundaries=tuple(bounds),edge_corr=True)
  File "/Volumes/My Passport for Mac/python_script/functions.py", line 91, in merger
    merged_ds = merge_datasets(datasets,nodata=np.nan,method=custom_method,bounds=boundaries)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rioxarray/merge.py", line 180, in merge_datasets
    merged_data[data_var] = merge_arrays(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rioxarray/merge.py", line 108, in merge_arrays
    merged_data, merged_transform = _rio_merge(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rasterio/merge.py", line 191, in merge
    first_profile = first.profile
AttributeError: 'RasterioDatasetDuck' object has no attribute 'profile'
```

Looking through merge.py in rioxarray, RasterioDatasetDuck is an object used to try and 'trick' rasterio into thinking that the xarray.Dataset is in fact a rasterio dataset. I also notice that in the class there is no point where this object is given a profile attribute (unless I have missed something). The class looks as such:

```
class RasterioDatasetDuck:
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    This class is to provide the attributes and methods necessary                                                                                                                                                                             
    to make the rasterio.merge.merge function think that                                                                                                                                                                                      
    the xarray.DataArray is a rasterio Dataset.                                                                                                                                                                                               
    """

    def __init__(self, xds: DataArray):
        self._xds = xds
        self.bounds = xds.rio.bounds(recalc=True)
        self.count = int(xds.rio.count)
        self.dtypes = [xds.dtype]
        self.name = xds.name
        self.nodatavals = [xds.rio.nodata]
        res = xds.rio.resolution(recalc=True)
        self.res = (abs(res[0]), abs(res[1]))
        self.transform = xds.rio.transform(recalc=True)

    def read(self, window, out_shape, *args, **kwargs) -> numpy.ma.array:
        """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        This method is meant to be used by the rasterio.merge.merge function.                                                                                                                                                                 
        """
        data_window = self._xds.rio.isel_window(window)
        if data_window.shape != out_shape:
            # in this section, the data is geographically the same                                                                                                                                                                            
            # however it is not the same dimensions as requested                                                                                                                                                                              
            # so need to resample to the requested shape                                                                                                                                                                                      
            if len(out_shape) == 3:
                _, out_height, out_width = out_shape
            else:
                out_height, out_width = out_shape
            data_window = self._xds.rio.reproject(
                self._xds.rio.crs,
                transform=self.transform,
                shape=(out_height, out_width),
            )

        nodata = self.nodatavals[0]
        mask = False
        fill_value = None
        if nodata is not None and numpy.isnan(nodata):
            mask = numpy.isnan(data_window)
        elif nodata is not None:
            mask = data_window == nodata
            fill_value = nodata

        return numpy.ma.array(
            data_window, mask=mask, fill_value=fill_value, dtype=self.dtypes[0]
        )
```

This RasterioDatasetDuck object is *not* passed through rasterio.open() in merge.py, and rasterio's merge function immediately attempts `profile = first.profile` where 'first' is said object.

In effect, it seems like rasterio is trying to get an attribute that rioxarray does not assign to the object.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have an older version of rioxarray. This issue has been resolved:

- https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/pull/217
- https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/225